# Support for Vista?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I could find nothing on the main VSCode site that listed the version of Windows supported. When I install on Vista, I get an error:

The prodcedure entry point RegisterTouchWindow could not be located in the dynamic link library USER32.dll.

So I'm guessing this is for Windows 7 and up?

Comment: I'm using VSCode on Windows 7. It's just a preview version. If it didn't work on Vista, you'd better send feedbacks to Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

Vista is not supported.

Isidor, vscode team